# Contact Form Not Working and coming up with no direct access

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I feel as if everything is correctly done but when submitting the form it comes up no direct access. This is from a template website that didnt have a contact form so i found one online but it doesnt seem to be working with it.

here is the html

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                         <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <textarea rows="6" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message" required="">
</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                        <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="SEND">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Here is the php

```
<?php
    /**
     * sends mail submitted from the contact form
     */

    /*
        EDIT BELOW
     */
    $to_Email       = "appydevelopers@gmail.com"; //Replace with your email address
    $subject        = 'Appydeveloper Site'; //Subject line for emails
    /*
        EDIT ABOVE
     */


    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest')
        die("No direct access.");

    if(!isset($_POST["name"]) || !isset($_POST["email"]) || !isset($_POST["message"])) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //additional validation
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Server error, could not send email. Sorry for the inconvenience.'));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'text' => 'Message successfully sent!'));
        die($output);
    }
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean "it comes up no direct access"? is there an error message? are you redirected to a page? give more details on what is happening

Comment: whats the name of the page with the form, and whats the name of the page with the php code?

Comment: yeah its an error message that comes up on a differant page

Comment: http://appydeveloper.uk/tab1.html thats the page with the form and this is the page with the php http://appydeveloper.uk/mail.php

Comment: what page? ok so you didn't answer all my questions. What page is which code on? what is the whole error message? I really can't help you if you don't give this information... and I don't understand why I must ask the same question more than once... I mean forget it, maybe you don't want help

Comment: when i submit the form on http://appydeveloper.uk/tab1.html i am redirected to http://appydeveloper.uk/mail.php and there is a message saying no direct access thats all i know i dont realy know php that well btw

Comment: Insert your http://appydeveloper.uk/tab1.html url in first conditions

Comment: could you point out where that would be i have no knowledge on php

Comment: just remove this if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest')
        die("No direct access."); OR modify

Comment: Could  you please provide some more details about the problem? An error message would be extremely helpful. What pages you're working with will also help a lot. The code line that's causing the error could also help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are not calling this php file through Ajax why are you checking it here `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])` This is used when you are calling through Ajax. So it is not set at all.

comment this line and check

```
//if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest')         //die("No direct access.");
```